# Kohana cache module on dynamic pages

Tags: php, caching, dynamic, kohana

I'm working on a website with user-specific homepage. Will Kohana regenerate cache everytime when different user opens homepage? Link to homepage is constant for every users, but content will be generated on basis of to what user is subscribed. If Kohana's default cache doesn't work here, what pattern of caching do you suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache [works](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/cache/usage#setting-a-value-to-cache) with cache keys

```
Cache::instance()->set($key, $value, $lifetime);
```

So, if your cache key the same for every user, main page will be the same too. You can generate cache key for every user (something like `mainpage_user1`, `sidebar_user18` etc). But this is useful onle for systems with limited user count.

Anyway, you should cache raw data (news list, article comments...) before linking it with user data.